# Is it possible to recover data of AWS ElastiCache (redis) without creating extra cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I didn't find an option to recover a Redis cluster to a previous time point.

All I can do is to seed a new cluster from the backup snapshot then remove the original cluster. Problem is the connection point information changes as well and I have to update any other resource to pick up the new configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, AWS doesn't offer a way to do this. You can do this manually using some open source tools.

1. Export your back to S3. This will create a .rdb file
2. Download the .rdb file to an ec2 instance
3. Then use one of the open source tools to parse the rdb file and insert the data into the existing elasticache redis

Two open source tools that will help you do this -

1. https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-cli-tool, see the redis-mass-insertion section
2. https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools - see the --protocol command (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool).

These tools will also help you to restore only a portion of the data if you so desire.

Comment: OK, this is workable. The feature I'm looking for is a fair requirement though and not difficult to implement, I'm wondering why it's not supported.

Comment: Does redis-rdb-tools have any scale limitation? Say if my redis cluster exports a 6GB snapshot, is redis-rdb-tools capable of supporting that?

Comment: It will support 6GB. Install the python-lzf package as well, that speeds up things. Time it once though to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: It will support 6GB. Install the python-lzf package as well, that speeds up things. Time it once though to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: My recommendation - if you want to do a full restore, doing it the aws way is better. Either make it easy in your application to change redis end points, or you can try a dns approach so that app doesnt have to change, you just update dns. If you want to restore subset of keys - use the approach in this answer.

Comment: I managed to do it the AWS way, also automated the step to update the endpoints. Thank you for the suggestions.